# My (AspectJ) jar does not recognize jointcuts

Tags: java, jar, aop, aspectj

Environnement : Simple Java stand-alone application. AspectJ jar inside.

I've two projects. The first one, say 'A' contains a custom method scope annotation and an aspect who is in charge of doing some task when the method is called.

The annotation :

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface AccessibleForRole {

    String value() ;

}
```

The aspect :

```
public aspect AccessibleListener {

pointcut verifyRole(): 
    (
            call(@AccessibleForRole * *())          
    );

    before() : verifyRole() { // do something
    }
}
```

I've done a jar file with thoses annotations/aspects.

After that, I create a model class in project A. I annotate a method with my annotation, run the program and I see the aspect catching the event and working on.

```
public class Model {

    @AccessibleForRole("admin")
    public void addUserToApplication(){
        System.out.println("in Model.addUserToApplication.");
    }
}
```

It works fine....but....
If I create a second project, project 'B' using jar 'A', and I create new classes, with methods that I annotate (same a Model for example), it seems that nothing special occurs. Nothing is catched.

Is it possible to create, in the future, something that have to be catched with AspectJ from project A jar, without having to recompile ?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: what exactly you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem resolved.
Thanks to a Maven plugin : http://mojo.codehaus.org/aspectj-maven-plugin/libraryJars.html

```
<groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
<artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
```

I put :

```
<aspectLibraries>
    <aspectLibrary>
       <groupId>myGroupId</groupId>
       <artifactId>jarA</artifactId>
    </aspectLibrary>
</aspectLibraries>
```

And when building or running, code from project B is correctly intercepted by the aspect define in jarA.

I hope this will help.